# Android Application Specific Video File Protection

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

I am developing a video player application, in which videos having copy rights are downloaded from a content management server.

I need set these video files access to my application only, and copy protected. It would be better if user cant see these files in file explorer.
**I would like to know is there a way to achieve this?**

Also the i decided to use phone's internal memory as the storage medium, 
**I also like to know is there any memory constraints/ access problem for video files that my application uses?**

Thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards
Anish

Answer (score 0):

Use your application's internal storage.

```
/data/data/<application_package_name>/<your_directory_name (If possible start with "." prefix)>
```

But even if any android device is **rooted** so user can easily get these video files. So if possible use `Encryption-Decryption` for these video files (These make video files access slow).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. While browsing I noted DRM can be useful. **I would like to know how it can be implemented? (in the server side and in my app).**